# Поиск буквы в файле: подсчитать количество гласных и согласных букв

Tags: php, файлы

Как дописать программу?
Дан многострочный файл с текстом, подсчитать кол-во гласных и согл букв и вывести их второй файл.

```
<?php
    // Открыть текстовый файл
    $f = fopen("1.txt", "r"); 
    // Закрыть текстовый файл
    fclose($f);
    // Открыть файл для чтения и прочитать строку
    $f = fopen("1.txt", "r");

/*if (strpos(file_get_contents("1.txt"), 'a'))
echo "Гласные: ";  
else echo "Согласные: <br />";*/

    fclose($f);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Подсчёт всех гласных и всех согласных букв по всему текст.файлу:

```
<?php

$file = 'alphabet.txt'; // Файл с текстом
$str = file_exists($file) ? file_get_contents($file) : '';
$patt = '~(?<vowels>[аеёиоуыэюя])|(?<conson>[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщъь])~iu';
preg_match_all($patt, $str , $a);

$vowels = count(array_filter($a['vowels']));
$conson = count(array_filter($a['conson']));

echo 'Гласных букв: '. $vowels .'<br />Согласных букв: '. $conson;
```